# How do I retrieve X from H2O GLRM Estimator

Tags: python, h2o

I am using H2O to fit a Generalized Low Rank Model (GLRM) in python. How do I extract X from the fitted model?

```
from h2o.estimators import H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator
import numpy as np

# Import the USArrests dataset into H2O:
arrestsH2O = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/pca_test/USArrests.csv")

# Split the dataset into a train and valid set:
train, valid = arrestsH2O.split_frame(ratios=[.8], seed=1234)

# Build and train the model:
glrm_model = H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator(k=2,
                                            loss="quadratic",
                                            gamma_x=0.5,
                                            gamma_y=0.5,
                                            max_iterations=700,
                                            recover_svd=True,
                                            init="SVD",
                                            transform="standardize")
glrm_model.train(training_frame=train)
```

I seem to be able to retrieve Y with

```
Y = glrm_model.archetypes()
np.shape(Y)
```

but I cannot find the method to retrieve X.